How to see output of rake tasks after closing the terminal window?
I have a rake task that requires several hours to run. I logged into my server, ran there the rake task and watched the outputs generated inside the terminal window.
Then my internet connection broke. Is there now a way to see the live output of the rake task?

Are you asking about this specific instance or about a more robust solution in general?

@Stefan it's about this specific instance, nothing complex.

What operating system is the server running on?

It's running on Ubuntu

I think I am a bit confused on the question in general. You are remotely connected to a server (through the internet), you are watching live output, internet goes down (no connection to the machine or any other web resources) but you still want to see live output? You could obviously log this to a file to review later but if you can't connect to the internet and you can't connect to the machine through a local intranet or by physically standing in front of the machine with a monitor, then there is no possible way to view live output.

Instead of a Rake task, I would suggest using one or even multiple Sidekiq jobs (or whatever tools you are using to run background jobs).
Such tools are well integrated into your application monitoring and logging tools by default, and often even have a web UI that allows tracking progress of an individual job.
Plus: Engineers usually are more experienced writing tests for background jobs than testing Rake tasks.

One additional advantage of Sidekiq/ActiveJob is that it's (more classically) object oriented while Rake is a DSL and can be kind of awkward to structure your code around. Often you end up with a rake task that just invokes some kind of class (like a service object) anyways.

@spickermann This was a one-time task where I needed to populate data to a new column in a database table, so as a "quick" solution, I went with the rake task (frankly using a Sidekiq job for this task didn't cross my mind)

Try the following:

Find the PID of your running rake command
Attach terminal to the last logs of the output of that process tail -f /proc/{PID}/fd/1. Alternatively can try to use more command instead of tail


Next time you could start a rake task in a session of such utils as tmux and screen, this way your terminal session would be stored even after connection break.
Alternatively, you could write your rake task output to a file (you can configure Rails.logger to do it)

thanks, I tested it earlier today, but it unfortunately does not produce any output.
